# How can I start activity from receiver as a single new activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am writing an app which need to show an activity over the lock screen when the device is locked.
I have another question to ask for the way to detect if the device is locked or the lock timeout of the device. If everyone knows please show me the way to do it.
[Question Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635221/android-get-lock-timeout-programmatically)

And this is the second question.

I have a mainactivity(A) to start a service. the service register a receiver to check if the device is screen off. 
When the device is screen off, a activity(B) will be shown over the lock screen.
I disable the keyguard and re-enable after my activity is closed to simulate this.

However, if the mainactivity(A) is running, no matter showing on the screen or onPause status, when the screen is off and activity(B) is shown, after i close the activity(B) with `finish()` in activity(B), mainactivity(A) shown after unlocking the device even mainactivity(A) is not shown on the screen before the device go screen off.

this is the code in receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Log.d("Receiver", "Screen ON");
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.setClass(context, activityB.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
        Log.d("Receiver", "Screen OFF");
    }
}
```

Maybe my english is poor to understand.

Here is the ideal flow

mainactivity(A) -> Button to start a service
service register a receiver
receiver detect if the screen is off, start activityB
activityB -> button to `finish()` -> show keyguard -> unlock -> show the previous view/activity before the device is locked

however
mainactivity(A) -> start a service -> service register a receiver -> press home button to minimize all running app/activity -> wait the screen timeout -> receiver detect screen off -> start activityB -> close activityB -> unlock -> mainactivity(A) shown

I guess the problem comes from `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`, activity(B) is started as a task, so when mainactivity(A) is running, closing activity(B) will return to mainactivity(A)

P.S. if I press the back button to close mainactivity(A), since the service is started, activity(B) is still shown when screen off, when activity(B) is closed, mainactivity(A) is **NOT** shown.

Thank you very much.