# Get "Screen lock" setting in Android programatically

Tags: android, keyguard, screen-lock

Is there a way of getting the current setting for Settings-->Security-->Screen Lock? It is the setting that can be "None", "Slide", "PIN", etc. I am not interested in changing it, just knowing the current one.

I'm only interested in telling "None" from any of the others, so that would work too. I have seen that for API 23 they have added [`DevicePolicyManager.setKeyguardDisabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setKeyguardDisabled(android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean)). I am looking for the equivalent getter, ideally for API 14 onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days of research I have come up to the conclusion that there is no way of doing this. `KeyguardManager` methods cannot tell the difference between `None` and `Slide`. There is no way of querying this from Android settings either.

The only way is to manually monitor `Keyguard` when the screen goes off and assume, after 30 minutes, that if it didn't show up it is because `None` is set. This is obviously not a good idea, but Android seems determined to not give much information about its locking preferences.

Answer (score 2):

I find answer in LockPatternUtils class. I write my code in kotlin, you can easy transfer to java code.

```
/**
* 判断手机系统是否关闭了锁屏界面。
* 如果第三方 ROM 更改了 LockPatternUtil 或者 UserHandle 类，调用此方法可能会抛出异常。
*/
fun isLockScreenDisabled(): Boolean {
    val lockPatternClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils")
    val lockPatternObject = lockPatternClass.getConstructor(Context::class.java)
            .newInstance(applicationContext)

    val isSecureMethod = lockPatternClass.getMethod("isLockScreenDisabled")
    var result = true

    try {
        result = isSecureMethod.invoke(lockPatternObject) as Boolean
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {

        val userHandleClass = Class.forName("android.os.UserHandle")
        val myUserIdMethod = userHandleClass.getMethod("myUserId")
        val userId = myUserIdMethod.invoke(userHandleClass)

        result = isSecureMethod.invoke(lockPatternClass, userId) as Boolean
    }

    return result
}

/**
* 判断手机系统是否启用了密码锁。
* 在 4.1 系统以下的版本，如果系统 rom 更改了 LockPatternUtil 类可能会抛出异常。
*/
fun isSecure(): Boolean {
    val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure
    } else {
        val lockPatternClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils")
        val lockPatternObject = lockPatternClass.getConstructor(Context::class.java)
                .newInstance(applicationContext)

        val isSecureMethod = lockPatternClass.getMethod("isSecure")
        var result = false

        try {
            result = isSecureMethod.invoke(lockPatternObject) as Boolean
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {

            val userHandleClass = Class.forName("android.os.UserHandle")
            val myUserIdMethod = userHandleClass.getMethod("myUserId")
            val userId = myUserIdMethod.invoke(userHandleClass)

            result = isSecureMethod.invoke(lockPatternClass, userId) as Boolean
        }

        result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DevicePolicyManager` is not the thing you are looking for. `DevicePolicyManager` is intended for apps that want to use Device Administration.

Use [`KeyguardManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html) to determine what sort of device locking is enabled and whether the device is currently locked.

Comment: Thanks. However, I need to tell the difference between Slide and None, and KeyguardManager does not allow it (it consider both unsecure). There is a way of querying other security settings (for example, this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17261469/2891462). Is there something similar for this setting?