# Using adb to check the screen lock type on Marshmallow

Tags: android, adb

I've seens topics for [checking if screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467920/how-to-check-if-screen-lock-is-enabled-in-the-settings-using-adb) using `adb` but not the type of specific way which can be "none", "swipe", "pattern" etc. Is there a way to check it?

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging, and it turns out that you are not the first person to try this. The short answeris that there is no answer.

[Read this...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624919/get-screen-lock-setting-in-android-programatically)

Unfortunately, the answer that it gives is not what you want to hear, but if you can give us some additional context, we may be able to help you find a workaround.

Comment: Hi - oh, I missed that post. What i'm trying to do is validate various Android settings as part of regression testing on Android images. I guess I'm stuck with UI Automator then :/